# documentation like sphinx for PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any available documentation libraries like Sphinx but for PHP?
http://sphinx.pocoo.org/

http://api.beatport.com

Is looking for something to create some documentation for a PHP project

Answer (score 1):

There is [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/). It parses the code for docstrings like sphinx and can output html, pdf ... Many projects - if not all - use phpDocumentor for documentation.

Tutorial: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.pkg.html

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned PHPDocumentor, there's also [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/) that I'm just starting to use.